# How to track down which chrome extension is generating popunders?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Observation: as of ~4 hours ago, my browser opens up a popunder on ppcorn.com at random intervals (every ~10-50 minutes). No software change in past ~4-6 months (excluding regular windows updates), ublock origin running, meaning no other windows should be able to open popunders (and none are of shady sites).  This leaves only one uncanny explanation: one of the many chrome extensions I use had a sellout event, and are now injecting malicious code (this is the only piece of software other than my operating system that auto-updates).

Things I've tried so far: opening up background page debugger on every chrome extension, and observing network tabs (to no discernable effect); checking last updates on every chrome extension (can't really know when the injection happened).

Assuming the above is the case, how can I track down which specific extension have sold out, and generating malicious behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just began happening to me too. The mention of 'ppcorn' made for easy searching.

Comparing our extensions will narrow the search. Mine:

- 1Password
- Augury
- Dark Reader
- Google Dictionary
- Google Docs Offline
- Hover Zoom+
- HTTPS Everywhere
- Mercury Reader
- MightyText
- Momentum
- Privacy Badger
- Promoted Pin Hider
- Qure
- Send to Kindle for Google Chrome
- Session Buddy
- Smile Always
- StayFocused
- Stylus
- The Camelizer
- uBlock Origin
- User-Agent Switcher for Chrome
- Video Speed Controller

Comment: Our matching plugins are: google's stuff (prolly nope), Session Buddy, uBlock Origin, >> Promoted Pin Hider <<. Yesterday I also confirmed that PPH was sending out _a lot_ of affiliate GETs to various sites in the background, so removed that; popunder has not occured since (~14 hours). This is my current-best guess on culprit

Comment: Hooray, high-five!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to open up the extensions page at `chrome://extensions`
and disable extensions one-by-one until this stops happening.

When the extension is found, you may either remove it or signal the problem to
the developer.

Comment: Popunder occurs once every 30 minute; got 23 extensions. Any way to run this in less than a week?

Comment: Use the old method of disabling half of the rest at each go.

Comment: You can also disable the add-one that were recently updated

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open Incognito window and see if the ppcorn.com is opening. If so, that is a sing of a adware on your computer.

To check this, download [MalwareBytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mwb-download/) and see if there are any malicious extensions. You can also go to **Settings > Advanced** and click on **Clean my Computer** option if you cannot download Malwarebytes.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue with 'ppcorn', here were my plugins:

- 1Password
- Adblock Plus
- Adobe Acrobat
- Chrome Currency Converter
- Google Docs Offline
- Netflix Party
- Reddit Enhancement Suite
- Steam Database
- The Camelizer
- The Great Suspender

I switched off

- Chrome Currency Converter
- Netflix Party
- Steam Database
- The Camelizer
- The Great Suspender

And the popunder stopped. Someone else mentioned having the same issue and having The Camelizer plugin, so my guess at the moment is that is the culprit.

Comment: Our matching plugins are: google's stuff, and Reddit Enhancement Suite. I think neither of those were problematic, see comment above re: suspect this was promoted pin hider; but rather one of these just share the same shady org behind buying plugins. Thanks for letting me know!